# CKEditor delete image with non-standard markup

Tags: ckeditor

In CKEditor i have xsl template (That is why i have xsl tags inside img). The problem is when i delete the image, the tags inside img are not deleted.

```
<span contenteditable="false">
<span contenteditable="true">
<img alt=" legenda" contenteditable="true" height="200px" id="legendImg" src="/rp/resources/css/images/tpl/legenda.png" width="400px">
<xsl:attribute contenteditable="false" name="src"><xsl:value-of contenteditable="false" select="legend"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
</img>
</span>
</span>
```

After clicking image in editor and deleting i get

```
<p><span contenteditable="false">
<span contenteditable="true">
<xsl:attribute contenteditable="false" name="src">
<xsl:value-of contenteditable="false" select="legend">
</xsl:value-of>
</xsl:attribute></span></span></p>
```

I need some pointers what is best approach to fix this problem. Maybe there is a simple way of fixing it, or should i listen to some kind of delete event.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot edit invalid HTML in a WYSIWYG editor like CKEditor. It uses native `contenteditable` as a base of its editing feature, so e.g. delete is handled by a browser (actually, this may change in the future, because of serious Webkit's bugs).

Although, it's not even a problem with backspaces handling, because XSL tags are removed from inside an image when CKEditor is parsing and fixing loaded content. To avoid that you could try to modify CKEditor's [DTD object](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/dtd.js), but still - hard to say whether browsers will be able to handle this correctly - I'm pretty sure that some of them won't.

So you need to remember that in WYSIWYG editor you're in fact editing a real web page, so you need to load content which is a valid HTML. Invalid parts you can protect using [config.protectedSource](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-protectedSource), but as image is configured by DTD as an empty tag it may not accept protected source inside it.

Comment: I already configured DTD so xsl tags are not removed when ckeditor is parsing html. It is working just fine. The problem is when i try to delete image manually.

Comment: So browser(s) are not able to remove those elements. Implementing your own backspace handling would be really complex, so I advice you to use `protectedSource`.